# Multiple goals in maven mojo

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I am developing a mojo that I envision will have 2 goals.

e.g.

```
    /**
    * @goal validate-user-config
    * @goal build-user-project
    */
```

So far I've only ever defined a single goal with the syntax above. My question is how can I create two goals and conditionally vary the behavior of the `execute()` function?

Comment: What kind of plugin? Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: You might want to consider using Java 5 annotations in your plugin instead of Javadoc-style annotations: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement two mojo classes one mojo class per goal in particular if they have different functionallity.

Comment: What khmarbaise said. :) Also, if the two goals share common configuration parameters, you might also want to create an abstract super-class for the two mojo classes. This pattern is common in many of the 'standard' plugins.

Comment: Yes it is the common way to do it.